# How to pivot results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have the following SQL tables:

[image: Diagram]

Each profile has multiple social media accounts and i am really interested  in getting the URLs for each profile, there are 5 social media platforms, Facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc.
I know i can get desired results by using 5 left joins but what i really want is to create just one join and then pivot the results. So what i'm really asking for is how to achieve this using PIVOT. Could some one provide an example or show me how to achieve it with such diagram.

I would like to get back a result consisting of ID(profile), and all social media platforms as separate columns with their corresponding URLs

The tables:

[image: SocialMediaPlatform]

[image: Profile]

[image: ProfileSocialMedia]

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database are you using? Please add the tag. Have you looked at your database's documentation for pivot examples?

Comment: @JK . . . Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi i have updated the question, I have but there is nothing of this sort there, My SQL knowledge is rather at beginners level...

Comment: Provide some data example, and expected output,  please.

Comment: @Chema Provided some data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    p.id,
    p.long_description,
    max(case when m.name = 'Facebook'   then pm.url end)  url_facebook,
    max(case when m.name = 'Twitter'    then pm.url end)  url_twitter,
    max(case when m.name = 'Instragram' then pm.url end)  url_instragram
from profile p
inner join profile_social_media pm on pm.profile_id = p.id
inner join social_media_platform m on m.id = pm.social_media_platform_id
group by p.id, p.long_description
```

Comment: This approach is definitely returning desired results, but i don't think that it is using PIVOT?